# how to drop malformed records while loading xls file to spark

Tags: apache-spark, xls

While loading csv file, there is an option to drop Malformed records. Can we do the same for XLS file load?
I have tried loading an XLS file (almost 1T size) and it shows this error:

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@339370e
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
  at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:300)
```

Please, advise. Thank you very much.

Comment: The error seems to suggest that a zip file was malformed, not a single line. Is this an xls file, or xlsx (which is a zip file)?

Comment: With the other options I am not sure you can use malformed like with csv. I would convert to csv - tip.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for (as done in Java for CSV):

```
spark.read().format("csv").option("sep", ",")
                          .option("header", true)
                          .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                          .schema(schema)
                          .load(filePath);
```

Here, we the `mode` will take care of `malformed` records and drop them when encountered.
Similarly, `header` is set to `true` which will not consider it as value and `separator` is defined as `comma` for `CSV` file format.

`spark` is the `spark session` to be created before the above snippet.